# install mysql in debian 9

Tags: linux, mysql, debian, apt

I need to install MySQL 7.5 on Debian 9 stretch, I tried to download it using PPA but when I try to update and complete download I get error apt-key expire.

```
Err:2 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian stretch InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 8C718D3B5072E1F5 MySQL Release Engineering 
Hit:4 https://packages.sury.org/php stretch InRelease
```

I tried to del the key and re-add it but still the same issue.
**how can I fix this issue, any help please!.**

Comment: I wasted a lot of time trying all possible solutions but to no avail.

Comment: Please notice that the LTS support for Debian 9 will end on 2022-06-30. It might be time to upgrade to Debian 11.

Comment: I have sup system that required Debian 9

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to find, because:

1. MySQL don't support this version, it is 8 or 5: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/
2. There is some confusion about MySQL version 7. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207506/what-happened-to-mysql-6-7

I found [this site](http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-Cluster-7.5/) that looks like an archive for MySQL made by the University of Kent. If you want to install it through the .deb files, I'll give you the steps below:

Get the `.deb` file, for example:

```
wget http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-Cluster-7.5/mysql-cluster-community-client-dbgsym_7.5.23-1debian10_amd64.deb
```

Install it:

```
dpkg -i mysql-cluster-community-client-dbgsym_7.5.23-1debian10_amd64.deb
```

Install dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```